# Where does Sonarqube collects data from?

Tags: sonarqube, code-coverage, jacoco, sonar-runner, cobertura

Last day I was configuring a jenkins job to run sonar on my java project. I had sonar and jacoco plugins configured in my job. Sonar was throwing some error for which my sysadmin asked me to remove the jacoco plugin configuration from job. I removed and now sonar is saying it cannot find cobertura.xml. 
So I am curious to know if sonar does analysis on already run jacoco or cobertura task or does it runs its own coverage analysis?

Comment: It would be really helpful to provide the SQ version you use as well as the plugins versions : java, cobertura plugins especially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer : In general, coverage is imported to SonarQube by reading a coverage report generated prior to any work of sonarQube.

Longer answer : Historically (read, about two years ago), SonarQube used to try to run coverage tool for java. This was a nightmare to maintain for every use cases and as such it is now up to the developers to provide a coverage report to SonarQube which will only act on those data (linking them to source, compute metrics, display them nicely).

In your case, that means you most probably have the cobertura plugin installed on your SQ instance and it is looking for a report to import.